# Glow effect on line bar using Chart.js in React

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Anyone know how to add a glow effect to line chart in [www.chartjs.org](http://www.chartjs.org) using react?

I've got the chart displayed

```
<Line
    data={{
      datasets: [
        {
            type: 'line',
            backgroundColor: "black",
            borderColor: "#5AC53B",
            
            borderWidth: 2,
            hoverBorderColor: "red",
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#5AC53B',
            pointHoverBorderColor: '#000000',
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 6,
            data: data,
        },
      ],
    }}
  />
```

But dont think there is a property available to give the line specifically a box shadow or glow effect? I've seen it done before but not in react.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `Chart` export of `react-chart-js2` to give drawn lines a glow.

**Example**

```js
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';

// Example taken from https://codepen.io/kurkle/pen/zYYPagB
let draw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw = function() {
  let chart = this.chart;
  let ctx = chart.ctx;
  let _stroke = ctx.stroke;
  ctx.stroke = function() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.shadowColor = ctx.strokeStyle;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
    _stroke.apply(this, arguments);
    ctx.restore();
  };
  draw.apply(this, arguments);
  ctx.stroke = _stroke;
};
```

Comment: @JamesWuhan `Line` is just a React component, but the `Chart` export is the chart.js library that you want to modify.

Comment: nice just pasted that in, make sure you import both you're {line, chart} like so